# Как работает наследование Java

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Не могу понять почему не работает базовый метод.
Создал абстрактный класс `Rodent` для задачи интерфейса. Метод `toString` должен во всех производных классах делать одинаковую работу - возвращать значение поля `name`. 
В main я заполняю массив ссылок `Rodent` случайными производными классами после чего в цикле печатаю их в консоль. Согласно методу `toString` должно выводиться поле name которые переопределены в каждом производном классе. Но выводится только поле `Rodent.` Даже если создать ссылку сразу на подкласс, а не на базовый все равно выводит поле базового. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы наследуемый метод `toString` возвращал значение поля своего класса, а не производного?

```
    import java.util.Random;
abstract  class Rodent{
    private String name = "Rodent";
    abstract void eat();
    abstract void run();
    abstract void sleep();
    public String toString(){return name;}
}
class Humster extends Rodent{
    private String name = "Humster";
    public void eat(){System.out.println("Humster.eat()");}
    public void run(){System.out.println("Humster.run()");}
    public void sleep(){System.out.println("Humster.sleep()");}
}
class Rat extends Rodent{
    private String name = "Rat";
    public void eat(){System.out.println("Rat.eat()");}
    public void run(){System.out.println("Rat.run()");}
    public void sleep(){System.out.println("Rat.sleep()");}
}
public class Z1 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    public Rodent getRodent(){
        switch (rand.nextInt(2)){
            default:
            case 0: return new Humster();
            case 1: return new Rat();

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Z1 zz = new Z1();
        Rodent[] rr = {zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),zz.getRodent(),};
        for(Rodent rt : rr){
            System.out.println(rt);
        }
        Rat rrr = new Rat();
        System.out.println("Test Rat " + rrr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. Потому что наследуемый метод не знает ничего о подклассе. Поэтому нужно перекрыть метод `toString()` в подклассе и пользоваться полиморфизмом.

Сделать так, чтобы можно было пользоваться своим подклассом, ну это вроде что-то объясняет выше сказанное. Но, помимо этого желательно было бы наследовать не только метод `toString()`,  но и его поля, тогда не нужно будет их дублировать в подклассе.

Comment: >Наследуемый метод не знает ничего о подклассах.
Да, но он же работает с полем которое есть у каждого наследуемого класса.
Например видел такой случай: базовый класс имеет метод получающий 2 числа и возвращающий их сумму. И наследуемый от него класс имел этот же метод, хотя тот небыл переопределен. Так почему мой базовый метод при наследовании возвращает значение поля базового класса, а не того подкласса, который я хочу напечатать? Ведь есть примеры методов, которые работают без переопределения одинаково для всех производных классов

Comment: Нет, ты ошибаешся, читай *лучше* мой ответ и не пиши тафтологию

Comment: Можете указать в чем моя ошибка? Производный класс неявно содержит непереопределенные методы и поля базового класса. Так почему метод вызванный для подкласса, не выводит собственное поле, а выводит поле базового класса?

Comment: Потому, что поля нельзя перекрыть, можно только методы. Почему метод не выводит собственное поле, как раз он выводит собственное, то которое наследуется. Избавься от дублирования полей с одинаковым названием и это решит проблему с выводом.

Comment: Надеюсь понятно, посмотри на свой код, у тебя везде поля с одинаковым названием, такие поля недоступны в подкласса, потому, что они *не* переопределяются, а дублируются и недоступны в подкласса. Я имею ввиду чистой java, без использования рефлексии.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я все понял. Был уверен что я переопределяю поля, а даже если и не переопределяю то все равно ожидал что вызовет одноименное собственное, а не унаследованное

Answer (score -1):

Могу ошибаться, поправьте меня, если это так, но я сталкивался с похожей ситуацией и решил ее следующим образом.

Действительно методы дочернего класса будут ссылаться на переменные родительского класса, если они (методы) не переопределены. Это решается **использованием ключевого слова super()** **в конструкторе дочернего класса**.
Таким образом можно не переопределять все методы родительского класса.

Comment: "Это решается использованием ключевого слова super()" - что "Это"?

Comment: "Это" описано в предыдущем предложении.
Если разворачивать мысль, то использование super() в конструкторе дочернего класса позволяет избежать получения значений из переменных в родительском классе (Именно эта проблема и беспокоит автора данного вопроса), которые (значения из родительского класса) не нужны, так как мы вызываем эти методы из дочернего класса и хотим получить значения переменных из дочернего класса.

Надеюсь такого пояснения достаточно.

Comment: Не надо "разворачивать мысль", которая является глупостью, а надо взять и прочитать, что такое вызов `super();` в конструкторе.

Comment: "Когда метод super() вызывается из подкласса, вызывается конструктор его непосредственного супер класса".

Так в чем же проблема, если мой способ решает такую же проблему, которая возникла у автора?

Comment: Ваш способ ничего не решает. С чего Вы взяли? Если Вы не напишете `super();` в конструкторе, то компилятор вставит это вызов за Вас.

Comment: Ну естественно в скобках нужно указать соответствующие поля из родительского класса, которые нам необходимы.

Comment: Это называется "параметры конструктора", а не "поля из родительского класса". В коде вопроса нет ни одного конструктора с параметрами.

Comment: Если конструктора нет это не значит, что его нельзя добавить, чтобы решить проблему автора.

Если конкретно вам не нравится мое решение, это не значит, что оно не может оказаться полезным кому-то еще.

Comment: Мне не может [не] нравиться то, чего нет.