# Наследование поля с модификатором private

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, getter, setter

Наследуются ли поля с модификатором `private`?

Вроде бы знаю, что нет. Но наткнулся на странный момент, ведь геттеры и сеттеры наследуются, а к чему они тогда обращаются?

Значит и приватные поля тоже должны наследоваться. Парадокс.

Comment: Похоже вам про наследование ничего не известно. Следует почитать вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/948570/204920) ответ.

Comment: @Roman C, спасибо! Кажется на этом примере начал понимать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Геттеры и сеттеры наследуются также как и другие доступные в наследуемых классах методы. Обычно они создаются чтобы иметь доступ к своим `private` переменным. Но следует заметить, что в этом случае наследуемые переменные перестают быть *немутируемыми*.